# OpenID Connect - Token Validation on client without call identity provider (IdP)

Tags: php, keycloak, openid-connect, middleware

I am looking for a way to validate an ID token without calling the IdP. The client app and the IdP run inside a controlled environment. For this reason, I want to validate the access token from OIDC, provided by Keycloak, direct in my Middleware. For performance reasons I dont want to call the OIDC endpoint from Keycloak again to validate an existing id/access token.

Is this possible?
What for information does the middleware need?

PS I am looking for an PHP implementation :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can include the public signing key in the client, then you can validate all the tokens offline. There are plenty of JWT-token libraries out there that can do that for you.

The most common case is that the client downloads the public key, but there is nothing stopping you from including it in the client. Just be careful if you update the keys in Keycloak, that you also update the client key.

To identify the user, classic session cookies are typically used. Using cookies is a well proven and secure way to identify the user after he has logged in. Assuming you protect the cookies in the right way. (samesite, secure, httponly)

This is a good video on the topic:

- [alert‘OAuth 2 0’; // The impact of XSS on OAuth 2 0 in SPAs](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lEnbi4KClVw&t=1934s&ab_channel=PhilippeDeRyck)

Comment: It all depends in the client is your backend PHP web application or you use a SPA (React/Angular) application. Typically, you only store a session cookie in the browsers and keep the tokens in the backend. If you can avoid it, you should not keep the tokens in the browser. IT is typically the receiver of the token that do the validation. The ID token is validated in the client and then the client issues a session cookie. The access token is mainly checked in by the receiver of it (The APIs).

Comment: also see the link I added in the answer.

Comment: If I do this and use auth grant flow from OIDC. What is stored in the browser? On calling my client app I got redirected to IdP where I log in and get redirected with "code", which can used by the client (My App) to get ID Token and Refresh token. But if my user (browser) is logged in, how can i validate tokens, if no token is stored in the user? Here i dont understand the OIDC flow. What is exactly stored in browser to identify him with the id token in my client? Does my client app need store the id token? And how can my app identify the same user just when the user is calling my app again?

Comment: I am using a backend PHP application as a client.

Comment: Some systems (like ASP.NET core) stores the received tokens (Access/ID/Refresh) encrypted in the session cookie. Yes, the cookie gets quite large, but that is the simplest way of storing them. As it is encrypted nobody (even the browser) can't decrypt it.

Comment: Hope this answers your question.

Comment: To sum up: i can store my tokens encrypted in session cookie. Or i can create a session cookie and build my own logic to minimize the size? Is there a standard way like OIDC wants me to handle this or is the free to decide? Thanks for helping, this was really helpful :)

Comment: It is all up to the specific implementation how and where the tokens are stored. I don't think the standard deals with that. I think a starting point is to put them in the cookie and if it grows to big (Do verify the cookie size), you can then look at storing the tokens in the backend (Database/in-memory/Redis...)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/236804/discussion-between-tore-nestenius-and-thomas-lippert).